# Некорректное время (часовой пояс) в ответе

Tags: java, spring, camunda

Работаю с использованием CamundaBPM, собираю статистику по задачам и не только, выполняю запрос на собственный эндпоинт (на RestController) и получаю список процессов и их задач

```
@GetMapping("/history")
public ResponseEntity<List<ProcessDto>> getHistoryProcesses(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

Класс:

```
public class ProcessDto {
private String id;
private Date created;
...
}
```

Тайм зона стоит Europe/Moscow, дата (если смотреть через дебаггер) верная и имеет такой вид:

`created: Mon Nov 01 14:16:40 MSK 2021` - тип Date, если его раскрыть, то

```
fastTime: 1635765400581

cdate: 2021-11-01T14:16:40.581+0300
```

В дебаг-консоли отображается верное время: `DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [[ProcessDto(id=2fe11c6f-3b05-11ec-978e-0242ac110003, created=Mon Nov 01 14:16:40 MSK 2021, ownerName (truncated)...`

Но проблема в том, что в ответе время отображается (в браузере, в постмане) на 3 часа меньше, чем должно быть.`"created": "2021-11-01T11:16:40.581+0000",` и имеет уже такой вид

Я предполагаю, что **проблема** в сериализации (?) дат такого типа, нужно менять конфиг Jackson или что-то еще?

Comment: в браузере отображается время в utc. Он же вам пишет, что часовой пояс +0000

Comment: @ArchDemon я понимаю, что это время в UTC, но почему оно такое? Почему не учитывается часовой пояс? Например, у человека в часовом поясе UTC+6 будет отображаться некорректная дата, так быть не должно. Или я не прав и думаю совсем не о том?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Время, которое отображается в консоли, выводится в формате по умолчанию, заданном в методе [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--):

> `public String toString()`
> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Jaskson использует свой класс для форматирования даты `StdDateFormat` **без часового пояса** и с локалью `en_US`, [используя формат ISO-8601](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/StdDateFormat.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.getDateFormat());
// DateFormat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat: (timezone: null, locale: en_US, lenient: null)
```

Соответственно, для изменения формата даты нужно либо сконфигурировать `ObjectMapper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mskDateMapper = new ObjectMapper();
mskDateMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US));
mskDateMapper.getDateFormat().setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));

ProcessDto p = new ProcessDto("id", new Date());
System.out.println(p);
System.out.println("----");
System.out.println(mskDateMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(p));
```

Вывод:

```
ProcessDto [id=id, created=Wed Dec 01 00:05:41 EET 2021]  // toString, default time zone
----
{
  "id" : "id",
  "created" : "Wed Dec 01 01:05:41 MSK 2021"
}
```

Либо задать формат на уровне сериализуемого DTO класса (тогда настройки маппера будут проигнорированы):

```java
static class ProcessDto {
    private final String id;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", timezone="Asia/Novosibirsk", locale = "en_US")
    private final Date created;
    // конструктор, геттеры, toString
}
```

Вывод в часовом поясе Новосибирска:

```
ProcessDto [id=id, created=Wed Dec 01 00:10:29 EET 2021]
----
{
  "id" : "id",
  "created" : "Wed Dec 01 05:10:29 NOVT 2021"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Сделал через аннотацию @JsonFormat, очень удобно